# Arraylist fills himself with lastValue i added

Tags: java, arraylist

i have an arraylist, and for some reasons it overwrites all previous values and only returns the last value added. So i have 3 objects to add, there will be 3 times the last object in the array. Here's the code: (sorry the variables aren't english):

```
public class Convertor {
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> hervormen = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
String Voornaam;
public Convertor(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> hervormen)
{
    this.hervormen=hervormen;
}
public ArrayList<HervormdeRij> Hervormen(){
    ArrayList<HervormdeRij> hervormd = new ArrayList<HervormdeRij>();
    HervormdeRij HervormdeRij = new HervormdeRij();
    int teller = 0;
    ArrayList<String> rij = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (teller < hervormen.size()){
        rij=    hervormen.get(teller);

        HervormdeRij.setDag(rij0(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setUur(rij1(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setDokterId(rij2DokterId(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setDuur(rij2Duur(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setAchternaam(rij5(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setVoornaam(Voornaam);
        HervormdeRij.setAdress(rij6(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setGemeente(rij7(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setTel(rij8(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setCommentaar(rij10(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setEmail(rij11(rij));


        hervormd.add(HervormdeRij);

        teller++;
    }



    return hervormd;
```

So "hervormd" is always 2000 times(the amount of "hervormen".size()) the last "HervormdeRij". I really don't see an error in my code? (And I Am 1000% sure that "hervormen" != 2000 times the same value.)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Still not able to understand the question.

Comment: Is your sample code right? It looks like the instance variable is the same as the class name and you're calling static methods on the Class instead of instance methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move `HervormdeRij HervormdeRij = new HervormdeRij();` inside the loop, or you will keep adding the same object every time:

```
ArrayList<String> rij = new ArrayList<String>();
while (teller < hervormen.size()){
    HervormdeRij HervormdeRij = new HervormdeRij();
    rij=    hervormen.get(teller);
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! :)
I Didn't knew that.

Answer (score 3):

You only instantiate one `HervormedeRij` object (before the loop) and you reuse that every time.

So you just need to move this line:

```
HervormdeRij HervormdeRij = new HervormdeRij();
```

inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize a new instance of your object before adding it in the array. Also, try to not define a variable with the class name, I changed the name of `HervormdeRij` variable to `hervormdeRij`

```
public ArrayList<HervormdeRij> Hervormen(){
    ArrayList<HervormdeRij> hervormd = new ArrayList<HervormdeRij>();
    HervormdeRij hervormdeRij;
    int teller = 0;
    ArrayList<String> rij = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (teller < hervormen.size()){
        rij=    hervormen.get(teller);
        hervormdeRij = new HervormdeRij();
        hervormdeRij.setDag(rij0(rij));
        hervormdeRij.setUur(rij1(rij));
        hervormdeRij.setDokterId(rij2DokterId(rij));
        hervormdeRij.setDuur(rij2Duur(rij));
        hervormdeRij.setAchternaam(rij5(rij));
        hervormdeRij.setVoornaam(Voornaam);
        hervormdeRij.setAdress(rij6(rij));
        hervormdeRij.setGemeente(rij7(rij));
        hervormdeRij.setTel(rij8(rij));
        hervormdeRij.setCommentaar(rij10(rij));
        hervormdeRij.setEmail(rij11(rij));

        hervormd.add(HervormdeRij);
        teller++;
    }

    return hervormd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Rename the as to not cause confusion with other code reading.  `HervormdeRij HervormdeRij = new HervormdeRij();` becomes `HervormdeRij hr = new HervormdeRij();`.
- Move it inside of your `while()` loop, so that every time through, you get new instances of type `HermorvdeRij`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to instantiate a new HervormdeRij in each iteration of the while. So it would look like this:

```
public ArrayList<HervormdeRij> Hervormen(){
    ArrayList<HervormdeRij> hervormd = new ArrayList<HervormdeRij>();
    HervormdeRij HervormdeRij;
    int teller = 0;
    ArrayList<String> rij = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (teller < hervormen.size()){
        HervormdeRij = new HervormdeRij();
        rij=    hervormen.get(teller);

        HervormdeRij.setDag(rij0(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setUur(rij1(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setDokterId(rij2DokterId(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setDuur(rij2Duur(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setAchternaam(rij5(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setVoornaam(Voornaam);
        HervormdeRij.setAdress(rij6(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setGemeente(rij7(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setTel(rij8(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setCommentaar(rij10(rij));
        HervormdeRij.setEmail(rij11(rij));


        hervormd.add(HervormdeRij);

        teller++;
    }
}
```